# Problema de redirección con VUE / NUXT

Tags: vue.js

he creado una web con NUXT que coge noticias de una API de Wordpress en JSON.

Si voy al enlace del Blog de la misma web https://www.tiroconarco.link/posts/ y pulso sobre la noticia que quiero, se carga correctamente.

Pero si cojo el enlace, lo copio y lo pego en otra pestaña del navegador, no funciona.

https://www.tiroconarco.link/post/guillermo-tell/

Se que es un problema de configuración de servidor, porque NUXT siempre se redirige al index.html. pero no encuentro como solucionarlo.

> Aclaro que si probais otras noticias del apartado POST puede ser que
> os funcionen ya que en NUXT cuando enlazas una noticia generada en una
> API externa desde una pagina .vue, al compilar NUXT se genera la
> pagina "fisica" de la noticia enlazada.
>
> Por ejemplo, el enlace
> https://www.tiroconarco.link/post/oneida-black-eagle-2-el-poleas-con-palas-de-recurvado/
> se genera con la info de la API pero como este enlace esta en la
> pagina  https://www.tiroconarco.link/distintos-tipos-de-arcos/
> (distintos-tipos-de-arcos.vue) al compilar genera el archivo fisico

¿Alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Gracias

Comment: Solamente te pasa con ese link (he probado con otros y funciona correctamente). En https://www.tiroconarco.link/posts/ si buscas el enlace de /post/guillerno-tell y lo pulsas tampoco  te está funcionando. Asegúrate de que tienes el componente **guillermo-tel.vue** creado en **/pages**

Comment: Pasa con los enlaces que coge desde la API y que no estan enlazados desde otra pagina .vue. Si cualquier enlace de dentro de POST es enlazado desde una pagina .vue, al hacer un GENERATE se crea la pagina .vue de esa noticia. El que pongo como ejemplo es una noticia nueva que no lo enlaza ninguna otra pagina .vue solo la llma el POST

Answer (score 0):

Estimado,

Debe registrar las rutas en el **nuxt.config.js**, específicamente en routes dentro de generate.

`generate: { routes: [ aquí va el arreglo de rutas ] }`

Como estas obteniéndolas desde una API, puedes generar un función anónima y asíncrona para que autocompletes las rutas.

Ejemplo:

```
generate: {
    routes: async () => {
        const routes = [];
        
        await axios.get('domain.com/api/v1/resources')
            .then(({data}) => {
                data.data.forEach((resource) => {
                    routes.push('/tu_super_ruta/' + resource.slug);
                });
            });
        
        return routes;
    }
}
```

Ahora, esto funciona siempre y cuando ejecutes **generate** (npm run generate), es decir que cada vez que se añada contenido en ese wordpress vas a tener que compilar para que vuelva a generar las rutas. Es una de las desventajas de optar por el contenido estático.

Saludos.